# Avoiding unpacking an array when altering its dimension

Tags: list-manipulation, packed-arrays

I am trying to flatten a matrix from 3-dimensional to 2-dimensional one.

The original one has dimension for example {10,120,120}:

```
list1 = RandomReal[1, {10, 120, 120}];
```

I want to convert it to a new matrix with {10,120*120} dimension. I am using:

```
On["Packing"]  (*For checking if exist unpacked arrays *)  
Flatten[Map[Flatten, {list1}, {-3}], 1];
```

But this will generate unpacked array. How should I avoid this issue?

Comment: Try `Flatten[list1, {{1}, {2, 3}}]`.

Comment: Thanks, it works!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An alternative to using [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten) as in the comments is to use [`ArrayReshape`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReshape). For large arrays, [`ArrayReshape`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReshape) should be significantly faster. For example:

```
list1 = RandomReal[1, {10, 1200, 1200}];
```

Comparison:

```
r1 = Flatten[list1, {{1}, {2, 3}}]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = ArrayReshape[list1, {10, 1200 1200}]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {0.120, Null}
>
> {0.025, Null}
>
> True